# How to move elements using std::move depeding on contents of vector in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector

I would like to know if I can move elements to another vector depending what there is in the vector. So for example I have a three vectors. Points, Player1 and Player1type. The point vector has integers in it, the player1type has strings in it and the player1 is supposed to have numbers from the points vector.

```cpp
int main() {

    vector <int> points {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector <string> player1type {"Power1", "Steal", "Power2", "Steal", "Power1"};
    vector <int> player1 {1,1,1,1,1};

    move(points.begin(), points.end(), player1.begin());


return 0;
}
```

As you can see in the code above it simply moves the elements in points to player1 by replacing the elements that are already in player1. What I want is the elements to move if there aren't any Steal elements in player1type. So it would be like this:

```cpp
player1type = {"Power1", "Steal", "Power2" ,"Steal", "Power1"};

Player1 = {1,3,5};
```

I have tried to implement this but I can't get it to work.

```cpp
int main() {

    vector <int> points {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector <string> player1type {"Power1", "Steal", "Power2", "Steal", "Power1"};
    vector <int> player1 {1,1,1,1,1};

    if (!player1type.empty() && player1type[0] == "Power1") {


    move(points.begin(), points.end(), player1.begin());

    }

    else if (!player1type.empty() && player1type[0] == "Power2") {

        move(points.begin(), points.end(), player1.begin());

    }

    else {

        cout << "Can't apply this sorry" << endl;       

    }

return 0;

}
```

This doesn't seem to work, all it does is adds in the numbers regardless of the statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your moving elements for the whole vector using `points.begin(), points.end()`.

For your conditional situation you should move if `player1type!="Steal"` and set up start and end move points accordingly, which you can achieve in a loop:

```cpp
vector <int> points {1,2,3,4,5};
vector <string> player1type {"Power1", "Steal", "Power2", "Steal", "Power1"};
vector <int> player1 {1,1,1,1,1};

for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
{  if (!player1type.empty() && player1type[i] != "Steal") 
   move(points.begin()+i, points.begin()+i+1, player1.begin()+i);
   else player1[i]=0;
}
for(auto i:player1)
cout<<i; // 1 0 3 0 5
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but when running it all i get is 
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: Made a typo, I transferred to `player1type` instead of `player`. Edited, check now.

Comment: @randomprogrammer also changed end point to `points.begin()+i+1`. See if the current code works.

Comment: yes the output is 11315 but as you can see i have steal in the vector so how can i remove the numbers for that specific element

Comment: Remove as in? you want to make them 0, like {1,0,3,05}? or {1,3,5}?

Comment: @randomprogrammer Just add the else part to make it zero or replace it with `erase()`. Editing that in my answer.

Comment: @randomprogrammer 0 would fit better if you were to do this again , rather than adding and removing each time with `insert` and `erase` respectively. However if you need the later, let me know. Edited